# How to check acknowledgement time in GCP pub/sub

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google Cloud Pub/Sub. I have created a topic and created a subscription. To process the message in Java. I have created a class MyReceiver and implemented the receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) of MessageReceiver interface.

```
@Service
public class MyReceiver implements MessageReceiver {

    
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
        System.out.println(message.getMessageId());

          executor.execute(() -> {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
                consumer.ack();
            });
    }

}
```

I want to check the acknowledgement time of the message that is successfully acknowledged after waiting for 60000 millis. Can anybody help to check the acknowledgement time? Ways if GCP provides any dashboard, logging or class which let me know this?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Pub/Sub does not track the time of acknowledgement, so it won't return the timing information about the acknowledgement.

To know the acknowledgement time of a message you have to track it manually in your code by adding the current timestamp while acknowledging the message.

For example, using sample code from [this](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#receive_messages) documentation I added  datetime.datetime.now() in the callback function:

```
def callback(message: pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message) -> None:
   print(f"Received {message}."+ str(datetime.datetime.now()) )
   message.ack()

streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")
```